# How to create multiple Rewrite-Rule for various site in single htaccess?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I am using a single database for two different sites. One is sitejury.com and the other is cdn1.sitejury.com. I'm trying to serve my files using the subdomain.

Previously I used simple https Rewrite for my domain. but now with my increasing need, it has become complex for me to set up.

1. I need to redirect both www.domain.com or domain.com to https://domain.com
2. Redirect all version of cdn.domain.com to SSL-https//:domain.com version except (option- 3)
3. Subfolder "wp-content" and "wp-includes" stay on both the domain domain.com and CDN domain with https. I only need these two files to redirect to their https version.

Comment: When you say a single database for two sites, is this 2 independent installs? Or is this a multisite install? Keep in mind that redirecting non-HTTPS to HTTPS isn't a WOrdPress question but an Apache question

Comment: not independent, no multisite but a single same database.

I created the subdomain directly on the main domain database and changed CNAME. everything exists on both sites. I need to limit access with rewrites.

Comment: Can you clarify further? If they both use the same install of WordPress and the same database, but it isn't a multisite install,  are they not the same website, how does that work? I don't understand, and I don't know what you mean by "I created the subdomain directly on the main domain database", that sentence doesn't make sense, can you word it differently ( be very precise with the terms you use )

Comment: Could it be that you actually have a single site that has 2 URLs?

Comment: I had site:domain.com at folder:domain.com first. Next, I created a subdomain cdn.domain.com directly on the folder: domain.com but not on the folder: cdn.domain.com. I just did it so that both site URLs get the same content from the same files. I need the CDN subdomain to serve the spesific folders and redirect all others to the main domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using this-

```
# TN - BEGIN https to https
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^scorewheel\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.scorewheel\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://scorewheel.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# TN - END http to https


# TN - Begin cdn redirection
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn.scorewheel\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cdn.scorewheel\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-includes/
RewriteRule (.*) https://scorewheel.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# TN - End cdn redirection



# TN - Begin cdn https
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/(.*) https://cdn.scorewheel.com/wp-content/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?wp-includes/(.*) https://cdn.scorewheel.com/wp-includes/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
# TN - End cdn https
```